# Inserting multi-dimensional array of zeros into a NumPy array along a given axis

Tags: numpy

I have an n-dimensional numpy array of shape: `(3, 3, 3, 64)`. I would like to increase the count along axis 2 by inserting zeros, so that the new shape is `(3, 3, 4, 64)`.

How do I insert zeros to increase a given axis value of a numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a zeros arrays with same shape as the input, but the third axis being of length same as the padding length, which is `1` for our case and concatenate with the input array along the same axis (third axis). For concatenation, we can employ `np.concatenate` or `np.dstack`(because its third axis).

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
z = np.zeros((3, 3, 1, 64),dtype=a.dtype)
out = np.concatenate((a,z),axis=2) # Or np.dstack((a,z))
```

Sample run -

```
In [182]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(3, 3, 3, 64)) # Array with all nonzeros

In [183]: z = np.zeros((3, 3, 1, 64),dtype=a.dtype)

In [184]: out = np.concatenate((a,z),axis=2)

In [185]: (out[:,:,-1,:]==0).all()
Out[185]: True

In [186]: out.shape
Out[186]: (3, 3, 4, 64)

# Another way to verify
In [187]: (out==0).sum()
Out[187]: 576

In [188]: 3*3*64
Out[188]: 576
```